Does the convergence of an integral representation of $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ imply a zero-free region
I'm watching a series of lectures by Professor Ram Murty on Analytic Number theory. In the second lecture, he derives the following:
$$-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$$
Which I understand. Then, using Abel's summation formula he shows that this is equal to:
$$s\int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(t)}{t^{s+1}} \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{s}{s-1}+s\int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(t)-t}{t^{s+1}} \, \mathrm{d}t$$
Where $\psi$ denotes the second Chebyshev function and the RHS is convergent for $\Re(s)>\varepsilon$, given by $\psi(x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^\varepsilon)$ and $\varepsilon<1$.
The professor says that since the RHS is analytic in this region, $\zeta$ contains no zeros there. I'm confused as I think that $\zeta'$ could have zeros which cancel with those of $\zeta$.

Please do not answer in the comments.

For every function $f(z)$ meromorphic on a disc containing a point $a$, $f'/f$ has a simple pole at $a$ unless $f$ is analytic and nonzero at $a$:
setting $r = {\rm ord}_{z=a}(f(z)) \in \mathbf Z$, near $a$ we have the series expansion
$$
f(z) = c(z-a)^r + {\rm higher \ order \ terms} \Longrightarrow f'(z) = rc(z-a)^{r-1} + {\rm higher \ order \ terms} 
$$
where $c \in \mathbf C^\times$, so
$$
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{(z-a)^{r-1}(rc + {\rm higher \ order \ terms})}{(z-a)^r(c + {\rm higher \ order \ terms})} = \frac{1}{z-a}(r + {\rm higher \ order \ terms}),
$$
so $f'(z)/f(z) = r/(z-a) + $ an analytic function around $a$. This has a pole at $a$ if and only if $r \not= 0$, which means $f$ has a zero or pole at $a$, in which case the pole of $f'/f$ at $a$ is simple. This is an extension of the comment by Conrad above, where the order of vanishing at a point is assumed to be greater than or equal to $1$. Everything goes through if the order of vanishing is negative too; we just need to avoid the function having order of vanishing $0$ at the point and the logarithmic derivative will have a simple pole at that point.
